# Sencha Touch 2 - "quietly" delete and update records in localstorage

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch 2 web app that is using a localstorage datasource to store a bunch of records.

I am able to perform all the usual crud operations fine, but I want to sync data using a webservice.  so periodically, the sencha app will poll the webservice for data changes and then make the necessary changes to the localstorage datasource of my sencha app..

My approach has been to use the following code block to run my sync process every 60 seconds:

```
var timerID = setInterval(function()
{
    MyApp.app.BackgroundProcessingMain();
}, (60000));
```

Inside "BackgroundProcessingMain()", I have various method calls to sync the various datastores (5)..

I call the webservice and get the data I require back, and then my approach has been to loop through the returned data, filter my store to the id of the current item of the returned data and then either delete it, or update it as necessary.
This works fine..  BUT, if this background process kicks off and I'm viewing a bound list control, my list which is using a filtered version of my datasource, suddenly drops down to only showing a single item, usually the last one in the returned data that needs to be synchronised since it was the last one that my update process filtered the store to operate on.

I thought I could use store.findById, get the record reference and update/delete that way, but if the particular ID is already being filtered out due to the view my bound list requires, the record isn't found in the store and therefore doesn't get updated..

What I'd like to be able to do is get a temporary copy of the store, unfiltered, be able to modify it, and then when my app then queries the localstorage next time a form is shown, it will just get the new updated data..

That is basically what I'm referring to as "quietly" in the title..

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what process I could take to get this update done..??

If you have example code, that would be awesome, but pseudo-code is fine..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `suspendEvents()` and `resumeEvents()` to temporarily prevent your store from firing events. You can then clear your filters, apply your updates (using `store.findById()`), and reapply your filters without your list changing.

```
var store = Ext.getStore('myStore');
store.suspendEvents();
store.clearFilter();
doThings(...);
store.filter(myFilters);
store.resumeEvents();
```

If you pass `true` into `store.resumeEvents()`, the buffered events will be discarded.